# Why I cannot qualify a aliased type with "unsigned"?

Tags: c++, linux, windows

I'm migrating my code from windows to Linux. There is no type named "__int64" on Linux, so I tried to define it myself with alias. My code is as follows:

```
#include <cstdint>

#if !defined(__int64)
typedef int64_t __int64;
#endif

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    unsigned __int64 ii64 = 0; // Error
    return 0;
};
```

When I compiled it, I got the following error:

> main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’: main.cpp:10:20: error:
>   expected initializer before ‘ii64’

I know that I can replace "unsigned __int64" with "uint64_t" or defining a new type, but why the preceding code cannot be compiled?

Comment: The word `unsigned` is not a qualifier. (The type `unsigned int` is not the type `int` with an added `unsigned`, it's a completely separate type.) You could always use a macro instead.

Comment: You are thinking of the typedef as a macro with relates substitution rules, but does not work that way.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but "define" is not working either.

Comment: If it worked, and I came along and decided I really like my `LargeInteger` class and instead wrote `typedef int64_t LargeInteger`, what would you expect to happen?

Comment: furthermore, `int64_t` is not a type that can be 'qualified' with `unsigned` anyway

Answer (score 4):

See the standard 7.1.6/2:

> As a general rule, at most one type-specifier is allowed in the
>   complete decl-specifier-seq of a declaration or in a
>   type-specifier-seq or trailing-type-specifier-seq. The only exceptions
>   to this rule are the following:

> signed or unsigned can be combined with char, long, short, or int.

Note that this doesn't mean unsigned can be combined with a typedef that might eventually be one of those types, it can only be combined with those other types directly.

Further, bear in mind that `__int64` is reserved for the compiler so defining it yourself is technically illegal. You're much better off using the standard `int64_t` and `uint64_t` types.

Comment: Thank you for so specific answer!

Answer (score 2):

Because typedef is not a macro. It is a new type! And you can not construct the types like this.

When you say `unsigned int`, it is not the same sematics as `const int`. `const` is a so-called *type qualifier*. It means, it does not specify a new type, but adds some property to already existing type. However, `unsigned` is not a type quialifier. `unsigned int` is a type on it's own.

Comment: This is an interesting question. macro-ness aside, I can't think of any reason that it wouldn't be valid to add the `unsigned` attribute, unless the compiler already considers the type to be completely defined and closed to any further attribute manipulation. A brief perusal of some of the standards documentation did not shed any light whatsoever on the subject, either pro or con.

Comment: Ah. It looks like @MarkB has nailed it.

Comment: I understand that `typedef` defines a new type. But macro `define` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, "unsigned int" is a type, but "unsigned int64_t" is not.

Comment: `typedef uint64_t __int64;` Is that not _extremely_ confusing and misleading? This wouldn't pass code review for me.

Comment: Agreed. Removed the ugly code. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from other things, that's because there is no type `unsiged int64_t`. Macro doesn't work for the same reason. But if you `#define __int64 int`, this will work, because there is a type `unsigned int`.